# rsync OpenIndiana repository on local server

Tags: rsync, repository, openindiana

I was looking for a repository from OpenIndiana but everything what I found is this: http://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/Making+a+LAN+mirror+of+global+package+repositories.

I would like to sync OpenIndiana repo on a local server. How can I sync it?

For example, for CentOS 7 I use something like this:

```
 rsync rsync://ftp.nluug.nl/centoslinux/7/ /mnt/mirrors/stage/centos/7/ /mnt/bin/centos7.exclude
```

Can I do something like this for OpenIndiana too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the link you provided:

#### rsync the package repository contents and/or updates

The whole repository can be updated (or even fetched right away, skipping the downloadable tarballs part) from the origin servers, but note that your repository would then include revisions for many releases of OpenIndiana (147-151a4 as of now) and take over 8GB of disk in size.

```
:; rsync -zavPHK pkg-origin.openindiana.org::pkgdepot-dev /export/pkg/dev/
```

[Source](http://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/Making+a+LAN+mirror+of+global+package+repositories#MakingaLANmirrorofglobalpackagerepositories-rsyncthepackagerepositorycontentsandorupdates)

Comment: Hello Jan! Thank you for your answer. When I try to clone it with the command provided by them I get this error message:`#>rsync -zavPHK pkg-origin.openindiana.org::pkgdepot-dev  /mnt/rpm-repo-rw/mirrors/stage/openindiana/
rsync: failed to connect to pkg-origin.openindiana.org: Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(124) [receiver=3.0.6]`

Comment: Please open a new question

Comment: Yes, you are right. The command is that one. The problem was the firewall. I forgot to open the port for it. Thanks!